# Postcode mapping (QGIS): how to transform OS csv data to an polygon map (.shp)?

Tags: qgis, voronoi-thiessen

I am trying to obtain a full England postcode map (polygons) out of free (and reliable) data out there.

The English National Office of Statistics does [share](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/uk-postcodes) a huge list of postcodes and some information I am not acquainted with and I was wondering if there was a way to use QGIS and this info to create a workable map to plot some points?

> This dataset contains information from the Ordnance Survey, consisting
>   of a list of all UK postcodes, together with their locations as
>   Easting/Northing and as latitude/longitude. Each postcode links to the
>   local authority district and LSOA that contains the postcode
>   'centroid'.

---

As per @Joseph advice, I downloaded an OS boundary map, then uploaded it on QGIS. All good.
Then I downloaded the OS Code-Point® Open, which is a .csv file. I uploaded one of the csv "ab" on QGIS (where X = Northing and Y = Easting; CRS = 27700).  I could see some points (see below).

[image]

Next I executed the command "Join attributes by location" (see below), but I didn't get the expected results (a map with the postcodes delimitation) - again, see below.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [link](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/)? You can download their shapefile which contains the main postcode boundaries.

Alternatively, you can get hold of district polygon shapefiles from [OS OpenData](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html) and with your postcode csv data, you can run a spatial join tool in QGIS such as:

`Vector > Data Management Tools > Join attributes by location`

Comment: yes I have seen the first links but I didn't understand why there was the first three digits + another number (e.g. KT12 5). I'll try the other tip

Comment: @pdx - I think the last digit represents the group of 'inter' postcodes. So KT12 5A contains postcodes such as KT12 5AA, KT12 5AB, KT12 5AD etc.

Comment: could you explain more in details this spatial join tool? I have a normal vector layer .shp of Britain and then I need to add all the .csv postcode files as "Add delimited text layer"?

Comment: @pdx - Yes, apologies, use the "Add delimited text layer" and choose the relevant settings. It should then appear as a point shapefile. Make sure the CRS (Coordinate Reference System) for both the point and polygon shapefile are the same and then you should be able to run the tool.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work - maybe because OS data (https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/code-point-open.html) only has northing and eastings?

Comment: @pdx - What doesn't work exactly? Do you receive an error when importing csv to QGIS or when running the spatial join tool?

Comment: I have edited the original post. What doesn't work is when I run the tool I guess

Comment: @pdx - Seems like you need a _very_ accurate polygon map in order to join each polygon to each postcode point. Otherwise you're mapping more than one post to each polygon which wouldn't really work...

Comment: yes, although 4-digits one would do. The one you linked earlier is great but I don't know to what extent it is reliable... and more than points I'm looking for shapes of the postcodes

Comment: @pdx - my company makes the postcode reconstruction in the [first link](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/). They're as accurate as you can using the free Ordnance Survey codepoint unit postcode data, so they're similar to what you'd get if you tried joining them in QGIS, See wikipedia for details on [postcode formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postcodes_in_the_United_Kingdom#Formatting). We don't provide unit postcode boundaries (e.g. for NW1 2AA) as all you would get would be a simple Voronoi cell shape (i.e. totally inaccurate).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to create a polygon layer that covers each postcode for free, then I've done something like this before using OS Codepoint Open (just for Milton Keynes I might add).  The [OS website](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/help-and-support/products/code-point-with-polygons.html) even describes how they made their data for the CodePoint with polygons layer (Look at 4th question "How accurate..."):

> Code-Point with polygons is derived from ADDRESS-POINT®, the Ordnance Survey dataset that provides National Grid (NG ref) coordinates for each postal delivery address in Great Britain, mainly to a 0.1metre resolution. The Thiessen process tessellates these points, then the address boundaries inside each postcode are dissolved away, leaving boundaries for the postcode units.

Essentially how they did this was to voronoi every postcode point, then dissolved the inner boundaries of all matching postcodes, giving the overall postcode area.  OS go on to explain they tidy the data up to follow natural break such as roads or rivers.

If you were to do this for the whole of the UK you would either have to merge all the CSVs together, or once an areas polygons have been created, then you will have to clean up any overlaps between neighbouring postcodes created from differenct CSVs.

Comment: As discussed in the answer above, we've done this for postcode area, district and sector levels available to download [here](http://www.opendoorlogistics.com/downloads/). Our reconstruction is based on CodePoint open though - which has geocodes to unit postcode level (a unit postcode typically covers around 15 houses). From the text you've quoted it sounds like Ordnance Survey do their Voronoi reconstruction based on address (building?) level geocodes, which would be a much more accurate reconstruction than can be done with free data (so more accurate than yours or ours).